# How to compare string value in IF condition

Tags: visualforce

Please don't mind if it's a simple question. I want to compare two strings but one string(`Pates de L'Ile`) contains this `'` which causes an error. Please check the code below

```html
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!(oppli.Product2.family =='Pates de L'Ile' && rowNum == 1)}" style="margin-left:10px" >
    <apex:image value="{!$Resource.PatesdeLIle}" width="180" height="100"/>
    <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

This code `oppli.Product2.family =='Pates de L'Ile'` throws error

> Error: EL Expression Unbalanced: ... `{!(oppli.Product2.family =='Pates de L'Ile' &amp;&amp; rowNum == 1)}`

So how to  compare String if its contain this  `'`

Answer (score 2):

In programming (in general, not just on the Salesforce platform), when you have a string that contains a character with a special meaning, you need to *escape* that character to be able to use it. "Escaping" a character tells the underlying system to *treat this thing differently than you normally would*.

The way you "escape" something is generally to add a backslash `\` right before the character you want to escape.

`rendered="{!(oppli.Product2.family =='Pates de L'Ile' && rowNum == 1)}"`

should be

`rendered="{!(oppli.Product2.family =='Pates de L\'Ile' && rowNum == 1)}"`

Comment: The code now saves successfully but it does not give me the correct result. I mean  image  should display when both strings are equal

Comment: @fawadkhan You also have the condition that `rowNum` must be 1 (and both conditions must be satisfied because you're using the AND operator (`&&`) ). Your use of `<apex:variable>` seems to be incorrect (it has no initial value), and it appears that you may be using it in an iteration component, a situation that [the documentation on `<apex:variable>` specifically warns against](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_variable.htm).

Comment: the value for `` rowNum ``  i initialize above ```<apex:variable value="{!1}" var="rowNum"/>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!Opportunity.opportunityLineItems}" var="oppli"> ```i used many  `` <apex:outputPanel`` to display image based on prouct.family   all are working good but only this one is not working

Comment: I think this ``\``  is not working on the VF page. Is there is any other way?

Answer (score 0):

So by using backslash `\` in a string like `Pates de L\'Ile`  will make string like this `Pates de L\'Ile` and the value coming from  `oppli.Product2.family` is this  `Pates de L'Ile` so both strings are not equal. To solve this using `JSENCODE()`  which will add backslash `\` in a string like

```
{!(JSENCODE(oppli.Product2.family)    == 'Pates de L\'Ile' && rowNum == 1)}"
```

Now both strings are equal